# Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot no longer supports Production slot name

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm adding this in the hope that it saves other people wasting time like I just have.  I can't currently explain *why* this has changed, but I can supply the resolution that's worked for me.

**TL;DR:** You no longer need to specify the production slot when using Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot, only supply -SourceSlot with the name of the slot you want to switch with your production slot.

**Error:**

Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot : The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/*SiteName*/slots/production' under resource group '*ResourceGroupName*' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName $SourceSlot -DestinationSlot ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.DeploymentSlots.SwitchAzureWebAppSlot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Old working code:**

```
Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName 'production' -DestinationSlotName 'staging' -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroup' -Name 'webapp'
```

**New working code:**

```
Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName 'staging' -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroup' -Name 'webapp'
```